# Tables with different character encodings in one database. Doctrine issue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a production database that contains tables with UTF8 encoding and tables with ISO Latin 1 encoded strings.
I told doctrine to handle the databse as ISO Latin 1 but this way I can't access strings in Tables with UTF8 encoding. I didn't find a Doctrine Table Option for character encoding nor can't I touch the data base as it is used in production. Do I have to extend doctrine myself or is there another option?

I thought about wrapping all string fields with something like CONVERT( COL USING utf8 ) in select statements. But could doctrine do that for me out of the box? I use symfony2 with doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/advanced-field-value-conversion-using-custom-mapping-types.html

I just use a custom DBAL type wrapping the columns with: binary convert(COL using utf8)